# Why is the entropy of a subsystem density matrix equal to that of the other subsystem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, entropy, quantum-entanglement

If we have some system $\rho_{AB}$ we can find the entanglement entropy as

$S(\rho_A)=S(\text{Tr}_B(\rho_{AB}))=S(\text{Tr}_A(\rho_{AB}))$

But why are the entropies of the subsystems $\rho_A$ and $\rho_B$ equal?

Comment: What do you know?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch the trace of all are 1, they are all hermitian. Also, the entanglement entropy should give "the amount of bits" that are entangled, and so it makes sense that it is the same on both subsystems. But why is this the case?

Comment: No, I mean: What do you know about bipartite pure quantum states? Or quantum information in general?  Have you for instance heard about the Schmidt decomposition?  I.e.: Someone who answers, where should they start with their explanation?

Comment: Good that you added the details to the argument!  You should have also caught the mistake I made ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a state $|\psi\rangle=\sum_{ij}C_{ij}|i\rangle|j\rangle$, the density matrix is

$$\rho=|\psi\rangle \langle \psi|=\sum_{ijkl}C_{ij}{C_{kl}}^*|ij\rangle\langle kl|$$

We find the reduced density matrix of $A$ by tracing out the $B$ subsystem
$$\rho_A=\text{Tr}_B\left(\rho\right)=\sum_x {}_{B}\langle x|\sum_{ijkl}C_{ij}{C_{kl}}^*|ij\rangle\langle kl|x\rangle _B=\sum_{ikx}C_{ix}{C_{kx}}^*|i\rangle\langle k|=\sum_{ikx}C_{ix}{C^\dagger_{xk}}|i\rangle\langle k|\ .$$
Equivalently, for B we find
$$\rho_B=\text{Tr}_A\left(\rho\right)=\sum_x {}_{A}\langle x|\sum_{ijkl}C_{ij}{C_{kl}}^*|ij\rangle\langle kl|x\rangle _A=\sum_{xjl}C_{xj}{C_{xl}}^*|j\rangle\langle l|=\sum_{xjl}C_{jx}^T{C_{xl}}^*|j\rangle\langle l|\ .$$

The reduced states for $A$ and $B$, respectively, are
$\rho_A=CC^\dagger$ and $\rho_B=C^T C^*=(C^\dagger C)^*$.  Now $CC^\dagger$ and $C^\dagger C$ have the same non-zero eigenvalues, and since they are real, also $C^TC^*$ has the same eigenvalues; and thus also the same entropy (which is a function of their eigenvalues).

Comment: This answer assumes that both subsystems have the same dimension, yes?

Comment: @Sal_99 No - the answer only talks about non-zero eigenvalues. If the dimensions are different, the number of zero eigenvalues will differ.

Comment: @Nobert Schuch, I don't understand how. If the dimensions are different, won't the sum over x done for the partial trace now be a sum over x in one case , and a sum over y for the other? And then, how would we be able compare two operators when they have different dimensions? (The C(adjoint)*C and C*C(adjoint)?

Comment: @Sal_99 The matrices A*B and B*A have the *same* non-zero eigenvalues (including degeneracies). If the matrices are not square, then the number of eigenvalues which are zero will be different.